# How can i get all folders's path int a directory in C#?

Tags: c#, path, directory, subdirectory

I have one folder's path, it has subfolders, i need the folderpath all of the subfolders inside the main folder what i got. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx) will give the list of all directories under the given directory:

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"Base folder Path");
```

You can include `searchPattern` and `searchOption` for more specific search

where `searchPattern` is

> The search string to match against the names of subdirectories in
>   path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal and
>   wildcard characters (see Remarks), but doesn't support regular
>   expressions.

and searchOption will be the

> [enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx) values that specifies whether the search operation should
>   include all subdirectories or only the current directory.

Comment: Any ideas to delete the oldest subfolder in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo parentdir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Program Files\\");
DirectoryInfo[] childdir = parentDir.GetDirectories();

foreach(DirectoryInfo subfolder in childdir)
    Console.WriteLine(subfolder.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] dictories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Please replace "C:\" with your desired Path

in the Variable "directories" you have all Subfolders of your Desired Path with ist subfolders.

If you Need only one Hirarchy of Subfolders you can use the Option "SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly"